# What does the percent sign mean in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, modulo

What exactly does this mean?

```
$number = ( 3 - 2 + 7 ) % 7;
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's the [modulus](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator, as mentioned, which returns the remainder of a division operation.

Examples:  `3%5` returns 3, as 3 divided by 5 is 0 with a remainder of 3.

`5 % 10` returns 5, for the same reason, 10 goes into 5 zero times with a remainder of 5.

`10 % 5` returns 0, as 10 divided by 5 goes exactly 2 times with no remainder.

In the example you posted, `(3 - 2 + 7)` works out to 8, giving you `8 % 7`, so `$number` will be `1`, which is the remainder of 8/7.

Comment: @zombat - 10 % 5 is 0 as 10 divided by 5 is 2 with a remainder of 0. Modulus is the remainder of the division operation.

Answer (score 22):

It is the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> `$a % $b` = Remainder of `$a`
>   divided by `$b`.

It is often used to get "one element every N elements". For instance, to only get one element each three elements:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Which gets this output:

```
0
3
6
9
```

*(Yeah, OK, `$i+=3` would have done the trick; but this was just a demo.)*

Answer (score 12):

It is the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator. In the statement `$a % $b` the result is the remainder when `$a` is divided by `$b`

Answer (score 4):

Using this operator one can easily calculate odd or even days in month for example, if needed for schedule or something:

```
<?php echo (date(j) % 2 == 0) ? 'Today is even date' : 'Today is odd date'; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`%` means modulus.

Modulus is the fancy name for "remainder after divide" in mathematics.

```
(numerator) mod (denominator) = (remainder)
```

In PHP

```
<?php
    $n = 13;
    $d = 7
    $r = "$n % $d";
    echo "$r is ($n mod $d).";
?>
```

In this case, this script will echo

```
6 is (13 mod 7).
```

Where `$r` is for the remainder (answer), `$n` for the numerator and `$d` for the denominator. The modulus operator is commonly used in [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) due to its special characteristic as a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).

Answer (score 3):

Since so many people say "modulus finds the remainder of the divisor", let's start by defining exactly what a remainder is.

> In mathematics, the remainder is the amount "left over" after
>   performing some computation. In arithmetic, the remainder is the
>   **integer** "left over" after dividing one integer by another to produce
>   an integer quotient (integer division).

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder

So `%` (integer modulus) is a simple way of asking, "How much of the divisor is left over after dividing?"

To use the OP's computation of `(3 - 2 + 7) = 8 % 7 = 1`:

It can be broken down into:

> ```
> (3 - 2 + 7) = 8
> 8 / 7 = 1.143 #Rounded up
> .143 * 7 = 1.001 #Which results in an integer of 1
> ```
>
> *7 can go into 8 1 time with .14 of 7 leftover*

That's all there is to it. I hope this helps to simplify how exactly modulus works.

---

Additional examples using different divisors with 21.

> Breakdown of `21 % 3 = 0`:
>
> ```
> 21 / 3  = 7.0
> 3 * 0 = 0
> ```
>
> *(3 can go into 21 7 times with 0 of 3 leftover)*

> Breakdown of `21 % 6 = 3`:
>
> ```
> 21 / 6 = 3.5
> .5 * 6 = 3
> ```
>
> *(6 can go into 21 3 times with .5 of 6 leftover)*

> Breakdown of `21 % 8 = 5`:
>
> ```
> 21 / 8 = 2.625
> .625 * 8 = 5
> ```
>
> *(8 can go into 21 2 times with .625 of 8 leftover)*

Comment: Since you are showing non integer math it should be mentioned that the function in PHP for floating point modulus is fmod()

Comment: @Daniklad that's outside of the scope of this question `What does % mean?`, since we're only talking about `%` (Integer modulus). Additionally my answer only demonstrates how modulus is being determined, so that the math being performed is understood. Not performing modulus on a `float` values where [`fmod()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) would be needed.